# Определитель массива float**

Tags: матрицы, математика, память, c++

Как изменить код программы, чтобы адекватно работал с массивами хотя бы размера 30x30, потому что так он уже на 10х10 забивает всю память и в итоге крашится. Я понимаю, что тут идет жуткая утечка памяти, и идет она в функции minor, но как решить эту проблему, не понимаю

```
float TMassive::determinant(float **A, int size)
{
    if (size == 1) {
        return A[0][0];
    }
    if (size == 2) {
        return (A[0][0] * A[1][1] - A[0][1] * A[1][0]);
    }
    float result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result += A[0][i] * determinant(minor(A, 0, i, size), size - 1); //
    }
    return result;
}

float **TMassive::minor(float **A, int row, int column, int size)
{
    float **M = new float *[size - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        M[i] = new float[size - 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
            if (i < row && j < column) {
                M[i][j] = A[i][j];
            }
            if (i < row && j >= column) {
                M[i][j] = A[i][j + 1];
            }
            if (i >= row && j < column) {
                M[i][j] = A[i + 1][j];
            }
            if (i >= row && j >= column) {
                M[i][j] = A[i + 1][j + 1];
            }
        }
    }
    return M;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, это логично. Рекомендую ознакомиться с RAII. Не думаю, что есть особый резон возвращать указатель на массив. Запросто можно переписать программу на работу с `std::vector` или сделать возврат `TMassive &` (если это то, о чем я думаю, причем именно по ссылке, чтобы не было лишних копирований объектов). А память течет, потому что Вы ее выделяете по `new`, но нигде не освобождаете. Получается, что при каждом вызове `minor` теряется `~(size-1)^2` памяти.

Comment: @perfect, при вызове оператора `delete` Вы не указываете объем высвобождаемой памяти, т.к. менеджер памяти при соответствующей операции выделения памяти `new` запомнил объем памяти объекта.

> количество элементов

Ну, главное не путать конструкцию `delete []` и `delete`, а также прочие способы работы с памятью.

Answer (score 5):

В том случае, если то, что Вы делаете не является учебным заданием:

детерминант гораздо проще и короче вычислять с помощью метода Гаусса (единственное деление)как "накопительное" произведение диагональных элементов на каждой итерации прямого хода после нахождения главной строки.

Если уж Вам так нравится создавать матрицу с помощью указателя на указатель (а здесь на форуме Вы встретите противников такого метода, например, уваж. [@avp](/users/232/avp)), то создайте класс.

```
class Matrix
{
  double**M;
  unsigned int nLines, nRows;
  public:
  Matrix(unsigned int l,unsigned int r);
  ~Matrix();
  double* operator [](const unsigned int i)const {return M[i];}
  ...
}
```

В конструкторе создавайте двумерный массив, в деструкторе - уничтожайте. Выгоды: не париться с утечками, и не нужна фукция minor(...);

Answer (score 1):

Да! Конечно, вычислять определитель в лоб, не методом Гаусса, - это круто! А ещё и с применением рекурсии! Здесь до самого последнего уровня рекурсии и удалять-то ничего нельзя. На её первом уровне (в цикле при фиксированном значении i) создаётся минор размером `(size-1) х (size-1)`. А вычисления с этим минором откладываются до самого последнего её уровня, начнутся уже после того, как рекурсия отмотает полностью стек назад. На следующем уровне рекурсии создаётся и хранится массив размером `(size-2) х (size-2)` и т. д. То есть одновременно должно храниться `2х2 + ...+ kхk + ... +(size-1) х (size-1)` элементов массивов, т.е. число порядка `(size-1)` в кубе. Не так и много. Но отработанные миноры не удаляются! Поэтому когда сработают все рекурсивные вызовы для вычисления одного опредлителя подматрицы размером `(size-1) х (size-1)`, будет создано и храниться в памяти `2х2х2 + ...+ k х k х k + ... +(size-1) х (size-1)х (size-1)` элементов типа `float`. Это уже число порядка четвертой степени size. Наконец, когда отработает весь цикл по i от 0 до size-1, в предложенной реализации одновременно должно будет храниться
порядка size в пятой степени чисел. Вроде бы даже при `size=30` не слишком много, в пределах 100-150 мегабайт. Но надо и с настройками менеджера памяти считаться. Если ему и позволено с таким количеством памяти работать, ему может не хватить разрешённого максимального количества элементов списка порождаемых блоков памяти. 
Поэтому обязательно при возврате с более глубокого уровня рекурсии на предыдущий нужно освобождать память, удалять отработанные миноры.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, делать нужно так:

```
float TMassive::determinant(float **A, int size) 
{ 
    if (size == 1) { 
        return A[0][0]; 
    } 
    if (size == 2) { 
        return (A[0][0] * A[1][1] - A[0][1] * A[1][0]); 
    } 
    float result = 0; 
    float **M;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        M =  minor(A, 0, i, size);
        result += A[0][i] * determinant(M, size - 1); // 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) 
         delete[] M[i];
    delete[] M; 
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Вроде того, только удалять надо не после цикла, а после каждого result +=

Answer (score -1):

Вы возвращаете уже уничтоженный массив M. Перенесите массив М внутрь класса TMassive.

Comment: Где массив M уничтожен!?

Comment: после выполнения функции становится не известно какой размер у массива и массив ли это вообще функция вернет только указатель на указатель и больше ничего. а вообще принято освобождать память там где она была выделена (внутри этого же блока).

Comment: Размер как раз ясен. Размер возвращаемого из ф-ции minor массива всегда size-1 x size-1

Comment: а память как будете высвобождать?

Comment: Вопрос не по адресу. Я бы вообще все по-другому сделал. Но коли уж так, то никто не мешает сохранять значение возвращаемого указателя, а потом чистить память...

Comment: вот видите вы знаете размер а компилятор не знает. а насчет вектора я с вами согласен, но есть конкретный код.

Comment: А причем тут компилятор? У меня есть ощущение, что у Вас, извините, полная каша в голове. Я прав?

Comment: нет не каша а книга. чтобы освободить память компилятору надо знать тип и количество элементов. если считаете по другому то поясните как.